# What is difference between en_core_web_sm, en_core_web_md and en_core_web_lg model of spacy?

Tags: python, spacy

I installed spacy on my system and I want to parse/extract person name, organization for english. But I saw [here](https://spacy.io/models/), there is 4 model for english. And there is [model versioning.](https://spacy.io/models/#model-versioning) I didn't get which model is large and which I have to choose for development?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`sm`/`md`/`lg` refer to the sizes of the models (small, medium, large respectively).

As it says on the models page you linked to,

> Model differences are mostly statistical. In general, we do expect larger models to be "better" and more accurate overall. Ultimately, it depends on your use case and requirements. We recommend starting with the default models (marked with a star below).

FWIW, the `sm` model is the default (as alluded to above)

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day. I will go with en_core_web_lg model.

Comment: @AnilJagtap I would suggest starting with `_sm` as SpaCy recommends though. That model is 29 megabytes only, while `_lg` is over 800.

Comment: I tested my some text with **_sm**. I don't care about size. I want result more accurate. And I think **_lg** is giving more accurate result than **_sm** model.

Answer (score 31):

The difference is in the accuracy of the predictions.

But, as you can see in the [comparison](https://spacy.io/models/en) in the spaCy documentation, the difference is very small.

The `en_core_web_lg` *(**788 MB**)* compared to `en_core_web_sm` *(**10 MB**)*:

- LAS: **90.07%** vs **89.66%**
- POS: **96.98%** vs **96.78%**
- UAS: **91.83%** vs **91.53%**
- NER F-score: **86.62%** vs **85.86%**
- NER precision: **87.03%** vs **86.33%**
- NER recall: **86.20%** vs **85.39%**

All that while `en_core_web_lg` is **79 times** larger, hence loads a lot more slowly.

What I recommend is using the `en_core_web_sm` while developing and then switching to a larger model in production.
You can easily switch just by changing the model you load.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
```