# spacy Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm' on windows 10 and Python 3.5.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

what is difference between `spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` and `spacy.load('en')`? [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487495/what-is-difference-between-en-core-web-sm-en-core-web-mdand-en-core-web-lg-mod) explains different model sizes. But i am still not clear how `spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` and `spacy.load('en')` differ

`spacy.load('en')` runs fine for me. But the `spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` throws error

i have installed `spacy`as below. when i go to jupyter notebook and run command `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` I get the below error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b472bef03043> in <module>()
      1 # Import spaCy and load the language library
      2 import spacy
----> 3 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
      4 
      5 # Create a Doc object

C:\Users\nikhizzz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in load(name, **overrides)
     13     if depr_path not in (True, False, None):
     14         deprecation_warning(Warnings.W001.format(path=depr_path))
---> 15     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
     16 
     17 

C:\Users\nikhizzz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model(name, **overrides)
    117     elif hasattr(name, 'exists'):  # Path or Path-like to model data
    118         return load_model_from_path(name, **overrides)
--> 119     raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
    120 
    121 

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

how I installed Spacy ---

```
(C:\Users\nikhizzz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder) C:\Users\nikhizzz>conda install -c conda-forge spacy
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\nikhizzz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    blas:           1.0-mkl
    cymem:          1.31.2-py35h6538335_0    conda-forge
    dill:           0.2.8.2-py35_0           conda-forge
    msgpack-numpy:  0.4.4.2-py_0             conda-forge
    murmurhash:     0.28.0-py35h6538335_1000 conda-forge
    plac:           0.9.6-py_1               conda-forge
    preshed:        1.0.0-py35h6538335_0     conda-forge
    pyreadline:     2.1-py35_1000            conda-forge
    regex:          2017.11.09-py35_0        conda-forge
    spacy:          2.0.12-py35h830ac7b_0    conda-forge
    termcolor:      1.1.0-py_2               conda-forge
    thinc:          6.10.3-py35h830ac7b_2    conda-forge
    tqdm:           4.29.1-py_0              conda-forge
    ujson:          1.35-py35hfa6e2cd_1001   conda-forge

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    msgpack-python: 0.4.8-py35_0                         --> 0.5.6-py35he980bc4_3 conda-forge

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    freetype:       2.7-vc14_2               conda-forge --> 2.5.5-vc14_2

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

blas-1.0-mkl.t 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   0.00  B/s
cymem-1.31.2-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.65 MB/s
msgpack-python 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   5.37 MB/s
murmurhash-0.2 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.49 MB/s
plac-0.9.6-py_ 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   0.00  B/s
pyreadline-2.1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   4.62 MB/s
regex-2017.11. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.31 MB/s
termcolor-1.1. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 187.81 kB/s
tqdm-4.29.1-py 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   2.51 MB/s
ujson-1.35-py3 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.66 MB/s
dill-0.2.8.2-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   4.34 MB/s
msgpack-numpy- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   0.00  B/s
preshed-1.0.0- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   0.00  B/s
thinc-6.10.3-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   5.49 MB/s
spacy-2.0.12-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:10   7.42 MB/s

(C:\Users\nikhizzz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder) C:\Users\nikhizzz>python -V
Python 3.5.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

(C:\Users\nikhizzz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder) C:\Users\nikhizzz>python -m spacy download en
Collecting en_core_web_sm==2.0.0 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.0.0
  Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz (37.4MB)
    100% |################################| 37.4MB ...
Installing collected packages: en-core-web-sm
  Running setup.py install for en-core-web-sm ... done
Successfully installed en-core-web-sm-2.0.0

    Linking successful
    C:\Users\nikhizzz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm
    -->
    C:\Users\nikhizzz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder\lib\site-packages\spacy\data\en

    You can now load the model via spacy.load('en')


(C:\Users\nikhizzz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder) C:\Users\nikhizzz>
```

Comment: I have a couple of possible ideas where the issue is.. First, try to re-download the model: `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Comment: By the way, 'en' defaults to 'en_core_web_sm', so they are actually identical. See [this](https://spacy.io/models/#available-models).

Comment: Just execution of `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` command is more than enough

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The answer to your misunderstanding is a Unix concept, **softlinks** which we could say that in Windows are similar to shortcuts. Let's explain this.

When you `spacy download en`, spaCy tries to find the best **small** model that matches your spaCy distribution. The small model that I am talking about defaults to `en_core_web_sm` which can be found in different variations which correspond to the different spaCy versions (for example `spacy`, `spacy-nightly` have `en_core_web_sm` of different sizes).

When spaCy finds the best model for you, it downloads it and then **links** the name `en` to the package it downloaded, e.g. `en_core_web_sm`. That basically means that whenever you refer to `en` you will be referring to `en_core_web_sm`. In other words, `en` after linking is not a "real" package, is just a name for `en_core_web_sm`.

However, it doesn't work the other way. You can't refer directly to `en_core_web_sm` because your system doesn't know you have it installed. When you did `spacy download en` you basically did a pip install. So pip knows that you have a package named `en` installed for your python distribution, but knows nothing about the package `en_core_web_sm`. This package is just replacing package `en` when you import it, which means that package `en` is just a softlink to `en_core_web_sm`.

Of course, you can directly download `en_core_web_sm`, using the command: `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`, or you can even link the name `en` to other models as well. For example, you could do `python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg` and then `python -m spacy link en_core_web_lg en`. That would make 
`en` a name for `en_core_web_lg`, which is a large spaCy model for the English language.

Hope it is clear now :)

Comment: Yes, it works! I'm using Spacy with a MacBook pro. What I needed was the module en_core_web_lg

Answer (score 232):

Initially I downloaded two en packages using following statements in anaconda prompt.

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

But, I kept on getting linkage error and finally running below command helped me to establish link and solved error.

```
python -m spacy download en
```

Also make sure you to restart your runtime if working with Jupyter.
-PS : If you get linkage error try giving admin previlages.

Comment: This worked for me too. In terminal, on my MacBook, I ran both `python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg` and `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` but continued to get the `OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.` error in Python when entering `spacy.load('en')` and `spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')`. Running `python -m spacy download en` in terminal and then `spacy.load('en')` in Python, I was able to load the model.

Comment: I was still unable to fix the issue until @talha-tayyab suggested a runtime restart. Kudoz to all of you, guys! https://stackoverflow.com/a/68012945/537648

Comment: When I try this, it gives me a syntax error for the word spacy

Answer (score 42):

The below worked for me :

```
import en_core_web_sm

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

Comment: incase if you anyone got an error (`No module named 'en_core_web_sm'`) after trying the above command then also execute [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57989297/3303074)

Comment: If this solution works for you then you can find out the path of the module using
```print(en_core_web_sm.__file__)``` and check that it is installed in the correct version of python that you want to be using

Answer (score 21):

Using the Spacy language model in Colab requires only the following two steps:

1. *Download the model (change the name according to the size of the model)*

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

2. *Restart the colab runtime!*
   Perform shortcut key： **Ctrl + M + .**

Test

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
```

successful!!!

Answer (score 19):

For those who are still facing problems even after installing it as administrator from Anaconda prompt, here's a quick fix:

1. Got to the path where it is downloaded. For e.g.

   ```
   C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\en_core_web_sm-2.2.0
   ```
2. Copy the path.
3. Paste it in:

   ```
   nlp = spacy.load(r'C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\en_core_web_sm-2.2.0')
   ```
4. Works like a charm :)

PS: Check for spacy version

Comment: I pasted in but got error `OSError: [E049] Can't find spaCy data directory: 'None'. Check your installation and permissions, or use spacy.util.set_data_path to customise the location if necessary.`, do you know what's going on?

Comment: This solution worekd for Google Colab as well.

Answer (score 15):

Try this method as this worked like a charm to me:

In your Anaconda Prompt, run the command:

```
!python -m spacy download en
```

After running the above command, you should be able to execute the below in your jupyter notebook:

```
spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

Comment: @ Pallavi Banerjee.. Your answer is not significantly different from Tarun Reddy's answer.

Answer (score 12):

Don't run `!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg` from inside jupyter.
Do this instead:

```
import spacy.cli
spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_lg")
```

You may need to restart the kernel before running the above two commands for it to work.

Answer (score 6):

Steps to load up modules based on different versions of spacy

download the best-matching version of a specific model for your spaCy installation

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
pip install .tar.gz archive from path or URL
pip install /Users/you/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

or

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

Add to your requirements file or environment yaml file. Theres range of version that one spacy version is comptable with you can view more under https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases

if your not sure running below code

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

will give off a warning telling what version model will be compatible with your installed spacy verion

enironment.yml example

```
name: root
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - anaconda
dependencies:
  - python=3.8.3
  - pip
  - spacy=2.3.2
  - scikit-learn=0.23.2
  - pip:
    - https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('/opt/anaconda3/envs/NLPENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1')
```

Try giving the absolute path of the package with the version as shown in the image.

It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

I am running `Jupyter` Notebook on Windows.

Finally, its a version issue, Need to execute below commands in conda cmd prompt( open as admin)

- pip install spacy==2.3.5
- python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
- python -m spacy download en

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
ChatBot("hello")
```

Output -
[image]

Answer (score 5):

a simple solution for this which I saw on spacy.io

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp=English()
```

https://course.spacy.io/en/chapter1

Comment: Can anyone please tell if this is correct or not? because it worked and nothing else above.

Comment: Yes! This works in PyCharm. Not sure why they show load method and then this version, like why is there two load methods.

Comment: This really works !

Answer (score 4):

First of all, install spacy using the following command for jupyter notebook
`pip install -U spacy`

Then write the following code:

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

Answer (score 3):

Open Anaconda Navigator. Click on any IDE. Run the code:

```
!pip install -U spacy download en_core_web_sm
!pip install -U spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

It will work. If you are open IDE directly close it and follow this procedure once.

Answer (score 3):

As for Windows based Anaconda,

1. Open Anaconda Prompt
2. Activate your environment. Ex: active myspacyenv
3. `pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz`
4. `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`
5. Open Jupyter Notebook ex: active myspacyenv and then jupyter notebook on Anaconda Promt

> `import spacy spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`

and it will run peacefully!

Comment: fyi for step #2 its conda activate myspacyenv.

Answer (score 2):

Loading the module using the different syntax worked for me.

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda Users

1. If you're using a conda virtual environment, ***be sure that its the same version of Python as that in your base environment***. To verify this, run `python --version` in each environment. If not the same, create a new virtual environment with that version of Python (Ex. `conda create --name myenv python=x.x.x`).
2. Activate the virtual environment (`conda activate myenv`)
3. `conda install -c conda-forge spacy`
4. `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

I just ran into this issue, and the above worked for me. This addresses the issue of the download occurring in an area that is not accessible to your current virtual environment.

You should then be able to run the following:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Answer (score 2):

Open command prompt or terminal and execute the below code:

```
pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

Execute the below chunk in your Jupiter notebook.

`import spacy`

`nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`

Hope the above code works for all:)

Answer (score 2):

I had also same issue as I couldnt load module using '''spacy.load()'''
You can follow below steps to solve this on windows:

1. download using *!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm*
2. import en_core_web_sm as *import en_core_web_sm*
3. load using *en_core_web_sm.load()* to some variable

Complete code will be:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

import en_core_web_sm

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

Answer (score 2):

This works with colab:

```
!python -m spacy download en
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

Or for the medium:

```
import en_core_web_md
nlp = en_core_web_md.load()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of any of the above, this solved my error.

`conda install -c conda-forge spacy-model-en_core_web_sm`

If you are an anaconda user, this is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This will work-

```
try:
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
except:
    print("Downloading spaCy NLP model...")
    print("This may take a few minutes and it's one time process...")
    os.system(
        "pip install https://huggingface.co/spacy/en_core_web_trf/resolve/main/en_core_web_trf-any-py3-none-any.whl")
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
```

Example / How to use-

```
import spacy
import os

try:
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
except:
    print("Downloading spaCy NLP model...")
    print("This may take a few minutes and it's one time process...")
    os.system("pip install https://huggingface.co/spacy/en_core_web_trf/resolve/main/en_core_web_trf-any-py3-none-any.whl")
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")


def perform_ner(*args, **kwargs):
    query = kwargs['query']
    # Process the input text with spaCy NLP model
    doc = nlp(query)

    # Extract named entities and categorize them
    entities = [(entity.text, entity.label_) for entity in doc.ents]

    return entities


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example input text
    input_text = "I want to buy a new iPhone 12 Pro Max from Apple."

    # Perform NER on input text
    entities = perform_ner(query=input_text)

    # Print the extracted entities
    print(entities)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running PyCharm on MacOS and while none of the above answers completely worked for me, they did provide enough clues and I was finally able to everything working.  I am connecting to an ec2 instance and have configured PyCharm such that I can edit on my Mac and it automatically updates the files on my ec2 instance.  Thus, the problem was on the ec2 side where it was not finding Spacy even though I installed it several different times and ways.  If I ran my python script from the command line, everything worked fine.  However, from within PyCharm, it was initially not finding Spacy and the models.  I eventually fixed the "finding" spacy issue using the above recommendation of adding a "requirements.txt" file.  But the models were still not recognized.

**My solution:** *download the models manually and place them in the file system on the ec2 instance and explicitly point to them when loaded.  I downloaded the files from here:*

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-3.0.0/en_core_web_lg-3.0.0.tar.gz

After downloading, I dropped moved them to my ec2 instance, decompressed and untared them in my filesystem, e.g. `/path_to_models/en_core_web_lg-3.0.0/`

I then load a model using the explicit path and it worked from within PyCharm (note the path used goes all the way to `en_core_web_lg-3.0.0`; you will get an error if you do not use the folder with the `config.cfg` file):

```
nlpObject = spacy.load('/path_to_models/en_core_web_lg-3.0.0/en_core_web_lg/en_core_web_lg-3.0.0')
```

Comment: awesome, this was what I was looking for. Have you found a way to cURL the tar files down? I think github does some kind of redirect to prevent people using it as a file storage.

Answer (score 1):

Check installed version of spacy
`pip show spacy`
You will get something like this:

Name: spacy
Version: 3.1.3
Summary: Industrial-strength Natural Language Processing (NLP) in Python

Install the relevant version of the model using:
`!pip install -U https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

Best is to follow the official spacy docs for installation (https://spacy.io/usage):

First uninstall your current spacy version

```
pip uninstall spacy
```

Then install pacy correctly

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above answers but could not succeed. Below worked for me :

(Specific to WINDOWS os)

1. Run anaconda command prompt with admin privilege(Important)
2. Then run below commands:

```
  pip install -U --user spacy    
  python -m spacy download en
```

3. Try below command for verification:

```
import spacy
spacy.load('en')
```

4. It might work for others versions as well:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have already downloaded `spacy` and the language model (E.g., `en_core_web_sm` or `en_core_web_md`), then you can follow these steps:

1. Open Anaconda prompt as admin
2. Then type : `python -m spacy link` [package name or path] [shortcut]

   For E.g., `python -m spacy link /Users/you/model en`

This will create a symlink to the your language model. Now you can load the model using `spacy.load("en")` in your notebooks or scripts

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

1. Went to the virtual environment where I was working on Anaconda Prompt / Command Line
2. Ran this: python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

And was done

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS :-
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_md

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced similar issue. How I resolved it

1. start anaconda prompt in admin mode.
2. installed both
   python -m spacy download en
   and
   python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
   after above steps only I started jupyter notebook where I am accessing this package.
   Now I can access both
   import spacy
   nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
   or
   nlp = spacy.load('en')
   Both are working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. I installed spacy and en_core_web_sm from a specific conda environment. However, I got two(02) differents issues as following:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '....\en_core_web_sm\en_core_web_sm-2.3.1\vocab\lexemes.bin'
or
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'.... It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

I did the following:

1. Open Command Prompt as Administrator
2. Go to c:>
3. Activate my Conda environment (If you work in a specific conda environment):

```
c:\>activate <conda environment name>
```

4. `(conda environment name)c:\>python -m spacy download en`
5. Return to Jupyter Notebook and you can load the language library:

```
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

For me, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Download `en_core_web_sm` tar file

Open terminal from anaconda or open anaconda evn.
Run this:

```
pip3 install /Users/yourpath/Downloads/en_core_web_sm-3.1.0.tar.gz;
```

or

```
pip install /Users/yourpath/Downloads/en_core_web_sm-3.1.0.tar.gz;
```

Restart jupyter, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in os console:

```
python -m spacy download en
python -m spacy link en_core_web_sm en_core_web_sm
```

Then run this in python console or on your python IDE:

```
import spacy
spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
conda install -c conda-forge spacy-model-en_core_web_sm

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/66528792/7709603

Answer (score 0):

```
In jupyter notebook

!python -m spacy download en.  
import spacy. 
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```