# Cant Locate Spacy French Model

Tags: python, spacy

I am loading Spacy French Model from Spacy Website and still not able to run it.

Have looked at the similar scenarios [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334304/spacy-cant-find-model-en-core-web-sm-on-windows-10-and-python-3-5-3-anacon) and [GitHub](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3663)

The package is successfully installed via pip as below and the other codes.

```
python -m spacy download fr_core_news_sm

from spacy.lang.fr.examples import sentences 
import fr_core_news_sm

nlp = spacy.load('fr_core_news_sm')
doc = nlp(sentences[0])
print(doc.text)
for token in doc:
print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
```

I get the error as below:
**[E050] Can't find model 'fr_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you have two versions of python installed?

If this were the case, you could be running one version of Python (say, Python 3.6) when calling

```
python -m spacy download fr_core_news_sm
```

Then, when you start your program, you might be running another version (say, Python 3.7). In this case, since the file hasn't been downloaded **for** python 3.7, you may get the error you are seeing.

You can check what is the default version of Python via the command line using:

```
python --version
```

If your application is being run on Python 3.7., you can download specifically to Python 3.7 by running:

```
python3.7 -m spacy download fr_core_news_sm
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this was the issue, i had to delete all versions of spacy and download it again conda and it worked