# Can't find model 'en_core_web_md'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp, spacy

I have installed spacy and downloaded en_core_web_sm with:
pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
Also tried
pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz

My spaCy version: 2.2.0
My Python version: 3.7.4

However, it still shows the error:
[OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_md'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuObm.png)

```
*import aqgFunction
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
# Main Function
def main():
    # Create AQG object
    aqg = aqgFunction.AutomaticQuestionGenerator()
    inputTextPath = "E:\Automatic-Question-Generator-master\Automatic-Question-Generator-master\AutomaticQuestionGenerator\DB\db.txt"
    readFile = open(inputTextPath, 'r+', encoding="utf8")
    #readFile = open(inputTextPath, 'r+', encoding="utf8", errors = 'ignore')
    inputText = readFile.read()
    #inputText = '''I am Dipta. I love codding. I build my carrier with this.'''
    questionList = aqg.aqgParse(inputText)
    aqg.display(questionList)
    #aqg.DisNormal(questionList)
    return 0
# Call Main Function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()*
```

Comment: FYI: the post title & description suggest there's a mismatch in `small` vs `medium` language model size between what was downloaded vs what was used.

Answer (score 15):

In Jupyter notebook use:

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

then:

```
[Ctrl+M] or `Restart runtime` from menu bar
```

Comment: also relevant for Jupiter Notebook over Google Colab

Comment: worked for me on the Colab as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this to install spacy and the model:

```
pip3 install spacy
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

And then run these in a python console.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Text here")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen when I had installed `en_core_web_md` into a remote interpreter for a container, but then ran the file with `if __name__ == '__main__'`, which used a venv where `en_core_web_md` wasn't available.