# spacy installation error OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to install spacy from anaconda prompt. I first opened anaconda prompt and ran it as administrator. After which I gave these commands. `conda install -c conda-forge spacy` and `python -m spacy download en`. Then, I go to my VScode and try to import it using this code:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

It gives me the following error:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I searched this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334304/spacy-cant-find-model-en-core-web-sm-on-windows-10-and-python-3-5-3-anacon/57989297) and used the commands `conda install -c conda-forge spacy` and `conda install -c conda-forge spacy-model-en_core_web_sm`. Still I get the same error.

Any help would be helpful. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Check Installation: Make sure that Spacy is installed correctly. You can do this by running the following command in your Anaconda prompt:

conda list | findstr spacy
This will show you the installed Spacy version

Check Model Installation: Ensure that the 'en_core_web_sm' model is installed. You can do this by running:
python -m spacy validate
This will check for installed models and their compatibility.

Reinstall the Model: If the model is missing or corrupted, you can reinstall it using the following command:

python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
Specify Full Path: Instead of relying on the default model loading mechanism, you can specify the full path to the model directory. You can find the model directory by running the following command in your Python environment:

import spacy
print(spacy.__file__)
Then, use the path to the 'en_core_web_sm' model in your code:

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('/path/to/your/spacy/models/en_core_web_sm')
Ensure that your Python environment has the necessary permissions to access the model directory.
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting spacy to load this model. 'python -m spacy validate' shows en_core_web_sm with a green checkmark, but 'spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')' fails because it's 'not a Python package or valid data directory'. print(spacy.__file__) just points me to __init__.py, not a model or a directory. Do I need to go into the site_packages directory where en_core_web_sm lives and do a pip install .?

Comment: Well, it's loadable from the site-packages directory if I specify the full path with the version number. It just can't be imported or loaded using the short name, for unknown reasons. That's good enough for my current purposes.