# Trouble in hosting Django project. Spacy nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

Tags: django, django-views, web-hosting, vercel

I am hosting a small Django project. The project is running perfectly on my local machine but on the deployed site, it says

```
OSError at /
[E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

The error is occuring in my `views.py` file where I had writted,

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

This is my requirements.txt file. (for hosting)

```
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.8
python-dateutil==2.8.2
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2021.5
gunicorn==20.1.0
spacy==3.1.3
```

I already tried adding `en-core-web-sm==3.1.0` but it's giving another error and frankly it's redundant because we already included `spacy==3.1.3`

I don't understand the reason for the error as everything is working fine when I run the project on my local machine. But it's not in the deployed site.

Here are the github repo and the hosted site links,
[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Midhunsrisai0/sensitive-info-masking),
[Hosted site (Vercel)](https://sensitive-info-masking.vercel.app/)
If you're trying out the website, upload a text file file and click `generate masked text`. Then you'll see the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spacy Can't find model 'en\_core\_web\_sm' on windows 10 and Python 3.5.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334304/spacy-cant-find-model-en-core-web-sm-on-windows-10-and-python-3-5-3-anacon)

Comment: @ewokx No, because that problem was encountered while the project was run on local machine. Mine works fine on local machine, the problem occurs on the deployed website.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
pip freeze
```

And you will see something like

```
en-core-web-sm @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-..
```

Hope this help